# Magento2:importing csv category include in menu enable

Tags: magento2, category, csv, topmenu

when i import product's csv. All products and category created successfully also all categories include in menu. I want when i import csv , all thing will be done , but not include in menu categories.
How can i stop categories to include in menu while importing the product's csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to Override the `protected function createCategory`.
And set the value : `  $category->setIncludeInMenu(true); to **'false'**.

```
namespace Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product;
```